# WymEditor problem with IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, wymeditor

I added to my web WymEditor. Everything works fine on firefox and google chrome. The only problem is IE9, where when I opening page with wymeditor, the new empty tab opens also. This is some kind of problem with iframe, I was searching for it in wymeditor code and found this :
"  //This function is executed twice, though it is called once!
    //But MSIE needs that, otherwise designMode won't work.
    //Weird."

Does anyone know how to fix it?